Correct parameter settings for Fortanix API Requests
I am trying to retrieve statistics from the Fortanix HSM via API calls.
The calls are structured as follows:
curl --request GET \--url https://amer.smartkey.io/sys/v1/stats/%7Bgroup_id%7D/group \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer REPLACE_BEARER_TOKEN' \ 
     --header 'accept: application/json'

It seems to be mandatory to enter parameters that I cannot interpret and set correctly:
StatsParams
object
- num_points integer
- top_count  integer (MAXIMUM 4294967295 MINIMUM 0)
- range_from integer
- range_to integer

Does anyone have experience using this setting?
